# Multiple index variables with 'as' in foreach loop to insert values in database php

Tags: php, mysql

The variable values `$rowData` and `$altertext` wants to be added in the databse tabe with 2 individual cloumn. So, I written this,

```
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "coupons");
$html = file_get_html('http://www.couponrani.com/');

foreach(($html->find('img') as $imgelement),($html->find('button') as $btnelement)) {
    $altertext = $imgelement->{'alt'};
    $rowData = $btnelement->{'data-coupon'};
    if(preg_match('/\bcoupons\b/i', $altertext, $matches) !== false){
        $imp = implode('',$matches);
            if(($imp !== '')&&($rowData != '')){
                $query = mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO couponrani(couponname,couponcode) VALUES ('$altertext','$rowData')",MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT );
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

But, When I do this it shows me that,

> ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'as' (T_AS) in
>   C:\wamp\www\exp.php on line 6

So, How could I correct my code...
What mistake I have done....?

Comment: That is not valid foreach syntax. You cannot loop through two arrays at once.

Comment: But, How can I  add both the variable values to the database...?

Comment: I had not get the answer in that link...Its not a duplicate question.....?